# how to make a basic shopping cart using node js and postgres sql?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

Are there any articles or blog posts or repos that can actually help me and walk me through creating a basic shopping cart using node and postgres sql?
Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I do understand node endpoints and req.params req.query (basic stuff). I was just hoping there was an article or blog post that will walk me through setting everything up and the logic like one cart per one user etc.

Comment: It might be possible with javascript and postgresql only, but it would be easier with a server application language such as php, coldfusion, .net, etc.

Comment: @DanBracuk: He's asking about Node.js.

Comment: [Designing a RESTful API With Node and Postgres](http://mherman.org/blog/2016/03/13/designing-a-restful-api-with-node-and-postgres/)